# How to remove autoscroll to a div id :target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have this accordion menu using `html` and `css` only, but the buttons are made of `:target` id. Is there any `javascript` that can remove the auto-scroll when I press any of the buttons? It hovers to the anchor `#id`.

There are lots of related answers on **stackoverflow**, but none of them did help me, please don't just suggest any other questions as an answer.

```css
#aconmine {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 90% !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  border: solid 3px white;
}

.aconmineli {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px 1px 1px 1px #efefef solid;
  background-color: #2A5581;
  display: block
}

.aconmineli h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border-bottom: 1px #efefef solid;
  background: #1D3D5F;
  background-image: url("http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/down.png");
  background-position: right 20px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
}

.aconminecontent {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.73s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.73s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom .5s ease;
  /* IE10 is actually unprefixed */
  -o-transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom .5s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.aconminecontent:target {
  max-height: 1000px !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  overflow: visible !important;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: -220px;
  padding: 200px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.aconminecontent:target .closeme {
  background-image: url("http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/up.png");
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px auto;
}

.aconminecontent p {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  margin-top: -47px;
}

.closeme {
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -23px);
}

.aconmineli a {
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  height: 43px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: : 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.aconmineli a:hover {
  height: 49px !important;
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="aconmine">
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab1"><h2>Пальтовая группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab1" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab2"><h2>Костюмная группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab2" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab3"><h2>Плательная группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab3" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab4"><h2>Спортивные изделия </h2></a>
    <div id="tab4" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab5"><h2>Текстильно-трикотажные изделия</h2></a>
    <div id="tab5" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab6"><h2>Изделия из Кожи и Замши </h2></a>
    <div id="tab6" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab7"><h2>Изделия из Натурального Меха </h2></a>
    <div id="tab7" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Here is a demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhfgjrqL/) of my accordion.

Comment: remove `height: 49px !important;` from `.aconmineli a:hover {..` viz is causing the issue.

Comment: I want to remove onclick jumping to #tab1, #tab2, #tab3 etc

Comment: can you explain better waht to you mean at the sentence: 
"but the buttons are made of :target id."?

Comment: you want to expand the `:target` only while others are collapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. The explanation is within the code - each comment for the relevant line of code.

```js
$('a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY
  // store the scrollY before the browser scroll to the :target
  var scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  // manually change the hash
  location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
  // scroll back to scrollTop
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
});
```

```css
#aconmine {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 90% !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  border: solid 3px white;
}

.aconmineli {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px 1px 1px 1px #efefef solid;
  background-color: #2A5581;
  display: block
}

.aconmineli h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border-bottom: 1px #efefef solid;
  background: #1D3D5F;
  background-image: url("http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/down.png");
  background-position: right 20px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
}

.aconminecontent {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.73s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.73s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom .5s ease;
  /* IE10 is actually unprefixed */
  -o-transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding-bottom .5s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out, opacity 0.7s ease 0.3s, padding .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.aconminecontent:target {
  max-height: 1000px !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  overflow: visible !important;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: -220px;
  padding: 200px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.aconminecontent:target .closeme {
  background-image: url("http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/up.png");
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px auto;
}

.aconminecontent p {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  margin-top: -47px;
}

.closeme {
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -23px);
}

.aconmineli a {
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  height: 43px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: : 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.aconmineli a:hover {
  height: 49px !important;
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="aconmine">
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab1"><h2>Пальтовая группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab1" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab2"><h2>Костюмная группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab2" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab3"><h2>Плательная группа </h2></a>
    <div id="tab3" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab4"><h2>Спортивные изделия </h2></a>
    <div id="tab4" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab5"><h2>Текстильно-трикотажные изделия</h2></a>
    <div id="tab5" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab6"><h2>Изделия из Кожи и Замши </h2></a>
    <div id="tab6" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aconmineli"><a href="#tab7"><h2>Изделия из Натурального Меха </h2></a>
    <div id="tab7" class="aconminecontent">
      <a href="#tabcloseme" class="closeme"></a>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mosh Feu. Your code looks fine, but it doesn't work on my WordPress website for some reason... it does work on jsFiddle and CodePen doe... when i press the button, it doesnt scroll to top.. but it also doesnt open the accordion... in other words preventDefault() works but location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); does not work.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Do you have a public URL for this site or maybe you can upload it just for now? In this way I can see the problem.

Comment: Here is a test page whit your code in it: http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/?page_id=2091 and a page without your code http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/?page_id=2094#tab4 .... dont mind the missing css code

Comment: You have an error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. Keep attention that `$` is `undefined`. I think it's a conflict between `jQuery`'s.

Comment: Omg.. i just had to wrap it in jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});